# Multipeer connectivity won't discover iOS device on university's network

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, multipeer-connectivity

I am using the iPhone simulator to connect to my iPhone with Multipeer connectivity, it works fine on my home network, but when I try to do it on my university's network it doesn't discover the other device. Could someone explain why this happens and if there are any ways to fix it?

Device to device is fine over bluetooth but I would like to test the app between the simulator and a device.

Comment: Best guess: Your university networks is "restricted", to avoid "stupid" things. It's for it security. Some are "ports" restricted, have a banned words, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to fix it would be to talk to IT services at your university about allowing mDNS/Bonjour.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can also test by turning on your Iphone **"Personal Hotspot"** (under Phone General settings) and connecting with Mac via bluetooth or WiFi and then try testing your app between simulator and Iphone, as long as they are connected in same **Personal Area Network**.

You can also bring app running on third device (may be IPad) into this **"Personal Area Network"**, that will connect to this active **"Personal Hotspot connection"** via **Wifi or Bluetooth** and test this app. Here one device (your Iphone) will act like bridge in mesh network.

These all device will able to share Message, Streaming and Resources to each other, as long as these app are using **"Multipeer connectivity framework"** are on same **personal area network**.